# Creating preferences private to only one activity

Tags: android

Can i define  a Preference that can only be accessed by only one activity and not shared among all activities of an application
i.e
even by using getSharedPreferences they are not accessed

```
class a extends PreferenceActivity
{
}
```

Comment: Your requirements are unclear,preference is for data sharing purpose,even if you use preference in one activity it is impossible to get data without corresponding key values.

Comment: i dont need in any project but to clear things i needed info on this.

Answer (score 0):

yes use a sharedpreferences specific for the activity:

```
getSharedPreferences("a", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

EDIT:

Scopes:
MODE_PRIVATE - application

MODE_WORLD_READABLE - system readable (deprecated, dangerous)

MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE - system writable (deprecated, dangerous)

MODE_MULTI_PROCESS - checks for changes in Preferences from other threads first (default for pre honeycomb)

Comment: if in any other activity i write getSharedPreferences("a",MODE_PRIVATE) will i not get the ref to it

Comment: in getPreferences() method if i pass mode as MODE_WORLD_READABLE OR WRITABLE what difference will it make from passing mode_private .kindly update as i am not able to clear this

Comment: preferences created in your application are available to ALL components of your application, Activities, Services, Receivers etc.